# Rails 4: group_by_day and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I use group_by_day to generate a chart with Chartkick.

E.g. I can display a chart that shows the total order count per day:

`<%= line_chart Order.all.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>`

I also want to have chart that shows the total order amount (amount_gross) per day. The catch here is that `amount_gross` is not a column in the actual database but a calculated field that depends on the VAT.

**Model Order.rb**

```
def amount_gross
  if vat
    amount_net * 1.1
  else
    amount_net
end
```

Normally, I would get the sum like this `sum = Orders.all.map(&:amount_gross).sum`

However, I don't know how I can do this with `group_by_date`

I tried `Order.group_by_day(:created_at).map(&:amount_gross).sum` but it throws an exception.

Comment: Does Order.group_by_day(:created_at) return a hash in the same way ruby's group_by would?

Comment: orders.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_day }

Comment: I got it with `= line_chart @data.group_by_day(:created_at).sum(:measure)` since `measure` was a field in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering and Grouping on the database level is much faster and efficient

```
 Order.sum('IF(vat= true,amount_net * 1.1,amount_net)',group:'day(created_at)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this i think if you want to stick to groupdate gem

```
Order.all.group_by_day(:created_at).values.flatten.map(&:amount_gross).sum
```